# How can I keep the music information on my vehicle's screen updated while playing music from my phone?

Tags: samsung, bluetooth-audio

How do I get the screen in my truck to stay refreshed/updated while playing music (via bluetooth) on my Samsung Galaxy s4?

The screen shows the first song's info like the song, artist etc. But when my phone starts playing the next song, the screen never updates with the new track information. Why won't it change with the info on the phone's screen?

I am playing music from Slacker Radio via bluetooth to my 2014 Silverado.